# Partition $\lambda/\mu$ notation?

Tags: notation, integer-partitions

When talking about two partitions $\lambda$ and $\mu$, what does the operation $$\lambda/\mu$$ mean? When Macdonald introduces partitions in the first chapter of "Symmetric functions and Hall polynomials", he defines addition, subtraction and multiplication of partitions - but no division. Nevertheless, he uses notation $\lambda/\mu$ later in the book. Any hint?

EDIT:

[user254665](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/254665/user254665) seems to suggest that $\lambda/\mu$ is basically the intersection of the two partitions in all of their elements. I.e. this would imply the following example

[image]

But I don't quite understand what \ $\{\phi\}$ is supposed to mean.

Comment: I haven't seen this but I would make  a guess:For  partitions of a non-empty set: For $S\in \lambda$ let $S/\mu=\{S\cap T : T\in \mu \}\backslash \{\phi\},$ and let $\lambda/\mu=\cup_{S\in \lambda}S/\mu.$  If this is wrong then what he says about $\lambda/\mu$ will probably  not make sense. If this is right, then it will.

Comment: @user254665 Thank you for the answer. I have edited the question above. Did I understand your idea correctly? What does $\phi$ mean?

Comment: $\phi$ is the empty set.

Comment: The only meaning of partition of a set $S$  that I know of, is a family $ F$ of pairwise-disjoint subsets of $S$ satisfying $\cup F=S$.  Sometimes, when $S$ is not empty, it is convenient that the empty set is not a member of $F$, and some authors  may include this as a  requirement in the def'n. If $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\lambda =\{ \{1,2,3\},\{4,5\}\}$ and $\mu=\{\{1,3,4\},\{2,5\}$ then $\cup_{s\in \lambda}S/\mu=$ $\{ \{1,3\},\{2\},\{4\}, \{5\}\}.$ As I said, see if this makes sense in the context of what is done in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $\lambda / \mu$ is the standard notation for a [skew shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Skew_tableaux).

The shape of a partition can be thought of as a geometrical arrangement of boxes (I use o's here).  For example, $\lambda = (5,3,2,1)$ is

```
o o o o o
o o o
o o
o
```

Now if $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are 2 partitions such that $\mu_i \le \lambda_i$ for all $i$, then $\lambda/\mu$ is a *skew shape*, obtained by removing the shape $\mu$ from the shape $\lambda$.  For example, if $\lambda$ is as above, and $\mu = (4,2,1)$, then $\lambda/\mu$ is the following, where the dots denote removed boxes that are not part of the shape.

```
. . . . o
. . o
. o
o
```

Comment: Thank you for the link and explanation! It is a bit weird, since Macdonald calls this operation $\theta=\lambda-\mu$ and not $\lambda/\mu$ in the book. He still uses the $\lambda/\mu$ notation also. I guess it is an abbreviation for $\lambda-\mu$?